# How should I implement authentication on my react news app?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, crud

I have built a news app using react and redux for various API requests. I have got a bit stuck when trying to implement some login/logout authentication for the app, I hope to eventually implement CRUD functionality for commenting on articles too.

The problem is I have been following a crash course in authentication with Firebase but it uses the useContext hook and this has thrown me off as I read you shouldn't use both redux and useContext as they ultimately do the same thing (I know not completely).

I just need pointed in the right direction of how I should proceed, what's best practice, should I be using redux to handle the authentication requests? and if so can anyone point me to some documentation that might be useful as I'm at a loss...

Comment: Redux should only store insensible database information . Redux is not used for authentication purpose, only to handle the current user id / email for example.
You must implement a proposer auth service like JWT token and then send a token to your front and store this token in the local storage (better if you refresh or the page or open a new tab (redux loose data) local storage keep them.

Comment: Thankyou for the clarification, I worded this poorly in hindsight. I thought local storage would be the way forward. I'll explore this more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how am using redux for authentication (idk if this the best practice )

```
useEffect(() => {
 auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      if (authUser) {
        //if the user loged in
        dispatch(
          setUser({
            uid: authUser.uid,
            photo: authUser.photoURL,
            email: authUser.email,
            displayName: authUser.displayName,
            plat: null,
          })
        );
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for this suggestion, makes sense, I'll see if I can work something out along these lines